# c# add values/show to DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView which has different rows and columns and it work perfectly when I add values to it

so I have 
dgv is a DataGridView

and the following line working perfectly

```
dgv.Rows.Add(setting[0], StringToInteger(setting[1]), setting[2], setting[3], setting[4]);
```

now the new change is setting[0] it was text cell, now it is DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
 and I have the values working,Not working, .... and may new things come in the future!

how to solve that

how to add a text value that it will show in the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn as a ComboBox ??

cheers

Comment: Not sure what are you really asking.
You should specify the available values for the ComboBox in the column definition and set specific values in rows instead of setting multiple values to each row. Unless you want different CBs for each row - in that case, you should really use a regular table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [templatefield](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479353.aspx),

this way you can bind a value to a new object (in this case a checkbox) trough a function.